# Ruby Argument Error, trying to transpose a matrix 90 degrees

Tags: ruby, argument-error

In the below code I am trying to transpose a matrix 90 degrees. But when I run the code I get an argument error:

I don't understand why this is happening as I clearly have an argument in the method definition. I would appreciate any input on why this error is occurring. Thanks.

```
irb(main):001:0> matrix1 = [
irb(main):002:1*   [1, 5, 8],
irb(main):003:1*   [4, 7, 2],
irb(main):004:1*   [3, 9, 6]
irb(main):005:1> ]
=> [[1, 5, 8], [4, 7, 2], [3, 9, 6]]
irb(main):006:0> def rotate90(matrix_input)
irb(main):007:1>   input_column = 0
irb(main):008:1>   input_row = 0
irb(main):009:1>   return_column = matrix_input.size - 1
irb(main):010:1>   matrix2 = []
irb(main):011:1>   mat1_size = matrix_input.size -1 
irb(main):012:1>   loop do
irb(main):013:2*     loop do
irb(main):014:3*       matrix2[input_column][return_column] = matrix_input[input_row][input_column]
irb(main):015:3>       input_column += 1
irb(main):016:3>       break if input_column >= matrix_input[0].size - 1
irb(main):017:3>     end
irb(main):018:2>     input_row += 1
irb(main):019:2>     input_column = 0
irb(main):020:2>     return_column -= 1
irb(main):021:2>     break if input_row >= mat1_size
irb(main):022:2>   end
irb(main):023:1>   matrix2
irb(main):024:1> end
=> :rotate90
irb(main):025:0> rotate90(matrix1)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
    from (irb):11:in `length'
    from (irb):11:in `rotate90'
    from (irb):25
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What are passing as an argument for `rotate90()`.

Comment: Sorry- I was using this matrix:      matrix1 = [
  [1, 5, 8],
  [4, 7, 2],
  [3, 9, 6]
]

Comment: What is the desired return value for `rotate90(matrix1)`, where `matrix1` is given in your comment? You should incorporate your comment and the desired return value in your question (by editing).

Comment: The error message says that at some point in your code, you are passing an argument to a method that expects no arguments. The error message also tells you where exactly that happens. Since you are not telling us where exactly that happens, that is all we can say about this problem.

Comment: In particular, the error message points to lines 7 (which is clearly not where the error is) and line 26 (which doesn't even exist). So, it seems that the error message you posted does not belong to the code you posted, since it points at lines that do not even exist in the code you posted. As long as we don't even have matching error messages and code, there is absolutely nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the original question with the exact code as I have pasted it into Terminal. The error seems to originate from line 11, but I see nothing wrong with that code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your error is on this line:

```
mat1_size = matrix_input.size -1
```

-1 is a negative number, and Ruby is interpreting it as:

```
mat1_size = matrix_input.size(-1)
```

The fix is of course:

```
mat1_size = matrix_input.size - 1
```

However your program still has some bugs, but this is the answer to your original question.

Comment: Thanks I never would have figured that out on my own. I was able to fix all the other errors.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to accomplish, it can be done as follows.

```
def rotate90(arr)
  arr.map(&:reverse).transpose
end
```

```
arr = [[1, 5, 8],
       [4, 7, 2],
       [3, 9, 6]]
```

```
rotate90(arr)
  #=> [[8, 2, 6],
  #    [5, 7, 9],
  #    [1, 4, 3]]
```

Note that

```
arr.map(&:reverse)
  #=> [[8, 5, 1],
  #    [2, 7, 4],
  #    [6, 9, 3]]
```

`arr.map(&:reverse)` is roughly shorthand for

```
arr.map { |a| a.reverse }
```

Note also that

```
4.times.reduce(arr) { |a,_| rotate90(a) }
  #=> [[1, 5, 8],
  #    [4, 7, 2],
  #    [3, 9, 6]]
```

returns the original array.

I see from the comment that the OP forgot to mention that neither `Array#transpose` or `Array#reverse` can be used. In that case we can take a different approach.

Observe that if `arr_new` is the array being constructed, then:

```
arr_new[i][j] = arr[arr.size-1-j][i]
```

for all `0 <= i <= arr.size-1` and `0 <= j <= arr.size-1`. We can therefore compute `arr_new` as follows:

```
arr_size = arr.size
  #=> 3 
last_idx = arr_size - 1
  #=> 2 
Array.new(arr_size) { |i| Array.new(arr_size) { |j| arr[j][last_idx-i] } }
  #=> [[8, 2, 6],
  #    [5, 7, 9],
  #    [1, 4, 3]]
```

Comment: Should have mentioned, the exercise prohibits use of .transpose and .reverse